# How do I debug when match-data is not getting set?

Tags: debugging, replace, match-data

Lately, I have seen some cases where I use re-search-forward to find a pattern, and then try to do something with the match, only to find that the match-data is apparently not correct.

For example, in a file I might have this text:

```
:RESULTS:
async-abcd-1234-output
:END:
```

I would expect this code to replace async-abcd-1234-output with "string"

```
(when (re-search-forward "async-abcd-1234-\\(output\\|value\\)" nil t)
  (let ((result-type (match-string 1)))
    (cond ((string= result-type "output")
           (replace-match "string")))))
```

That works when I run it in a buffer, but when I run it from a callback function I find that (match-string 1) is nil, and even (match-string 0) is "". What could be causing this? I feel like sometimes it works, and then stops working. It is baffling. Any ideas on how to debug this? When I use edebug, I can see the search appears to work, but the match-data isn't correct.

Comment: That is a typo. It should be joined to spell async. I must separated it to stop tat instance from getting copied. I am on the road now and can't seem to update it on my phone.

Comment: Okay, if `re-search-forward` is returning non-nil, but not setting the match data, my only guess is perhaps `inhibit-changing-match-data` somehow gets bound in that case?

Comment: You do not show anything about the calling context, so it is difficult to guess why `(match-string 1)` returns nil. Show the code for how you are using the code you showed. It sounds like you are searching in the **wrong buffer**, or with point at the **wrong buffer position**. You say that your code "works in a buffer, but not..." what do you mean by it not being in a buffer? Unless you provide a string argument, `re-search-forward` always searches the text in a buffer. The question now seems unclear - underspecified. Originally it seemed that the "typo" you refer to was your problem...

Comment: Have you tried using `debug-on-entry` or inserting calls to `message` to determine which buffer you are searching and where point is? If not, that would be a good first step.

Comment: Inspecting the match data with edebug  might be misleading as that could change while you're looking at it. Better insert a few good old 'message' calls to show context such as current buffer, text around point, match data etc. Both just after searching and just before replacing.

Comment: Thanks for the debugging tips. That is what I was looking for. It sounds like messages are among the best debugging options for this. i will give them a try!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to give the function a single string `REGEXP` argument, not two separate strings:

```
(re-search-forward "async-abcd-1234-\\(output\\|value\\)" nil t)
```

And you want to replace only the first match group, not the entire match, so you want this:

```
(replace-match "string" nil nil nil 1)
```

In other words:

```el
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (when (re-search-forward "async-abcd-1234-\\(output\\|value\\)" nil t)
    (let ((result-type (match-string 1)))
      (cond ((string= result-type "output")
             (replace-match "string" nil nil nil 1))))))
```

Comment: I did want to replace the whole match. The issue is the example I gave works in a buffer but not when I call it from code.  When called in a function it seems the match data isn't set correctly even though if I run with edebug I can see the search found the regexp in the buffer.

Comment: If you want to replace the whole match then just remove the last 4 args from the call to `replace-match`.